# Keep part of a window always visible

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

It is possible to use the [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API on Windows to keep a windows always on top of other windows, and there are many questions on StackOverflow dealing with this.

It is possible to keep only part of a Window always visible? I.e. specify a clipping region inside an existing window, and keep only that part visible?

A use case would be the following (on Windows):

- User clicks on icon to run app.
- User highlights a portion of the screen to focus on (similar to the Snipping Tool on Windows 7)
- The highlighted part of the screen remains always visible, even when other windows/programs are moved over the selected region.

I know the issues that would spring up with having other applications that are also set to being topmost. Just curious if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you change part of your window to be transparent to what's below (with a clipping region) it's still going to take all the mouse clicks, etc. that occur over the transparent part.

Your best bet is to create a new smaller window and make it top-most while hiding the main one.